# System Call Rosetta Stone?

Tags: system-calls

After seeing [this remarkable reference (A Sysadmin's Unixersal Translator (ROSETTA STONE))](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html) for sysadmins going between Unix systems, it made me wonder if anyone has put together such a similar reference for system calls between the many and various *nix operating systems?

Comment: `man` and `apropos` work everywhere.

Comment: Yes they do, but I would sure value seeing a nicely laid out version to really see things holistically like this. I think it could be especially helpful on some projects that are porting macOS tools to Linux at the moment and such as well as other interesting projects where there's a lot of back and forth and need for quick porting references.